# Invalid index 4 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=4

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following model:

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual int JobId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2), MaxLength(3)]
    public virtual Currency Source { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3), MaxLength(3)]
    public virtual Currency Target { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        var t = obj as ExchangeRate;

        if (t == null)
            return false;

        if (this.Job == t.Job & this.Source == t.Source && this.Target == t.Target)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (this.JobId + "|" + this.Source + "|" + this.Target).GetHashCode();
    }
```

I have the following AutoMapping override:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<ExchangeRate> mapping)
{
    mapping.Map(x => x.Source).CustomType<GenericEnumMapper<Currency>>();
    mapping.Map(x => x.Target).CustomType<GenericEnumMapper<Currency>>();

    // Define the composite key
    mapping.CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(e => e.JobId, "JobId")
        .KeyProperty(e => e.Source)
        .KeyProperty(e => e.Target);
}
```

And the following exported mapping file I have exported to try and help diagnose the issue:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="JFS.Data.Model.ExchangeRate, JFS.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="ExchangeRates">
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="JobId" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="JobId" />
      </key-property>
      <key-property name="Source" type="FluentNHibernate.Mapping.GenericEnumMapper`1[[JFS.Data.Currency, JFS.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], FluentNHibernate, Version=1.3.0.717, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880">
        <column name="Source" />
      </key-property>
      <key-property name="Target" type="FluentNHibernate.Mapping.GenericEnumMapper`1[[JFS.Data.Currency, JFS.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], FluentNHibernate, Version=1.3.0.717, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880">
        <column name="Target" />
      </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="Source" type="FluentNHibernate.Mapping.GenericEnumMapper`1[[JFS.Data.Currency, JFS.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], FluentNHibernate, Version=1.3.0.717, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880">
      <column name="Source" />
    </property>
    <property name="Target" type="FluentNHibernate.Mapping.GenericEnumMapper`1[[JFS.Data.Currency, JFS.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], FluentNHibernate, Version=1.3.0.717, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880">
      <column name="Target" />
    </property>
    <property name="Rate" type="System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Rate" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one class="JFS.Data.Model.Job, JFS.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Job">
      <column name="JobId" />
    </many-to-one>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have been tearing my hair out for most of the day now trying to resolve this issue with no success. I've read many posts and not been able to apply any solutions successfully. I am relatively new to NHibernate and keen to start using it more but so far there has proved a pretty steep learning curve to get a project up and running. Any advise on a resolution and explanation for the error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `KeyReference` instead of `KeyPropery` for many to one relationships that are part of the primary key.

```
.KeyReference(e => e.Source)
.KeyReference(e => e.Target);
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have overcome that exception. I now have a new exception, perhaps I should post as a new question?

An association from the table ExchangeRates refers to an unmapped class: JFS.Data.Currency

Comment: What is `GenericEnumMapper<Currency>`.  Is `Currency` the enumeration you want to use for `Source` and `Target`?

Comment: Yes Currency is the Enumeration for Source and Target. GenericEnumMapper allows me to save the string value of the enum rather than the integer representation in the database.

Comment: Thanks, after reading on further via that link I discovered that the cause of the 2nd error is because my Enum is in a different namespace to where the AutoMapper is allowing objects to be mapped. This brings me onto a new error now:

`Tried to add property 'Name' when already added`

Which has no indication as to which particular mapping is causing the issue.

Comment: @ProNotion I would ask a new question and post the full exception that is occurring `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have marked your answer as the solution and will post the new problem as a separate question.